# Securing NamedPipeServerStream on Unix

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, named-pipes, unix-socket

I'm working on a project that targets both `net451` & `netstandard1.6` that uses NamedPipeServerStream to use Named Pipes (on Windows) and Unix Domain Sockets (on macOS and Linux).

I'm looking for a way to secure these Pipes (and Sockets) so that the current authenticated user (and admin) are the only users that are able to read & write to/from these pipes.

I've pulled in:
https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.IO.Pipes.AccessControl/4.5.0-rc1

So that I can leverage PipeSecurity to secure the Named Pipes on Windows -- **that works really well!** -- but this API doesn't seem to have the ability to secure Unix Domain Sockets.

Ideally on Unix, I'd like to functionally do the same thing that this does:

`mkfifo mypipe -m700`

Which will give just the current user access to the socket.

Anyone have any idea how I could do this?

**I'll also ask this as an alternative...** if I could create these pipes in advance using `mkfifo` in the same process, would .NET Core leverage those if I specify the same name when creating the NamedPipeServerStream?

Comment: did you find a solution for this? I´m also working on a multi platform app and was wondering the same